How can I fix this Proton bug on Ubuntu 24.04?
Back in June, 2024, about half of my Proton games stopped working. I made a detailed report of the bug on Valve's Github, but no one has replied. I am curious to know what changed for Ubuntu 22.04 in June of this year. I am now on Ubuntu 24.04 and I am having the same problems. I'm not sure what my kernel version was when I had this bug, but I think the release schedule was on 6.5. Is it possible that my kernel updated from 5.15 to 6.5 without me doing it manually? I have my hardware details in the GitHub post. I have tried newer kernel versions, but they are not working. I am thinking about going back to a version of Ubuntu 22.04 that uses kernel 5.15. I would use snapshot to do this.

FYI:  The GA kernel for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS was 5.15 on release, and is still 5.15 now, and will remain that until it reaches EOL; the HWE kernel stack advances (using 5.19 from 22.10, 6.2 from 23.04, 6.5 from 23.10 before 6.8 from 24.04) as per https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack   Which kernel stack you use is set by your install media (ie. download time & what ISO you use to install; unless changed post-install).

I downloaded the Ubuntu 22.04 ISO on April 15, 2023. I downloaded Ubuntu 24.04 on June 17, 2024. I'm currently using 6.8.0-41-generic on Ubuntu 24.04. The installation media I used for Ubuntu 22.04 contains 5.15 & 5.19. Should I try a reversion to 5.15 to fix this problem?

"Rolling update model:
When using HWE, your system will automatically transition to the latest HWE kernel version as it becomes available, without needing to manually upgrade." (This seems like it could have caused a problem.)

To fix that bug, you need to study the logs along with the proton source code. Figure it out, make changes, and done. To know what changed in June, review the apt log.

"I downloaded the Ubuntu 22.04 ISO on April 15, 2023"  ??  There have been many 22.04 ISOs released; Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server, Ubuntu 22.04.1 Desktop, Ubuntu 22.04.1 Server, Ubuntu 22.04.2 etc... plus of course flavors. Some include the GA kernel stack (Server & flavors at 22.04 & 22.04.1) where others use HWE (Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 & flavors if 22.04.2 or later).   The 5.15 kernel was on ISOs using GA (& 22.04/22.04.1), 5.19 on 22.04.2 Desktop & flavor ISOs but Server 22.04.2 still had GA/5.15, 22.04.3 Desktop had 6.2 or 5.15, 22.04.4 had 6.5 or 5.15 etc
